# Collision within a poly

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, html5

For an html5 engine I'm making, for speed I'm using a path poly. I'm having trouble trying to find ways to get collision with the walls of the poly. To make it simple I just have a vector for the object and an array of vectors for the poly. I'm using Cartesian vectors and they're 2d.

Say **poly = [[550,0],[169,523],[-444,323],[-444,-323],[169,-523]]**, it's just a pentagon I generated.

The object that will collide is **object**, **object.pos** is its position and **object.vel** is it's velocity. They're both 2d vectors too.

I've had some success to get it to find a collision, but it's just black box code I ripped from a c++ example. It's very obscure inside and all it does though is return true/false and doesn't return what vertices are collided or collision point, I'd really like to be able to understand this and make my own so I can have more meaningful collision. I'll tackle that later though.

**Again the question is just how does one find a collision to walls of a poly given you know the poly vertices and the object's position + velocity?** If more info is needed please let me know. And if all anyone can do is point me to the right direction that's great.

Comment: Position and Position + Velocity/Time gives you a line segment.  Each point of your poly when combined to the next also gives you a line segment.  Given two line segments you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect to get where you want to go.

Comment: I was gonna link you to this tutorial before I saw Patrick's excellent comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/2D-Polygon-Collision-Detection. It's more indepth than what you need though

Comment: @Jeff +1 link it anyways, codeproject is a great reference =)

Comment: @PatrickHughes, I'm checking that out. It looks perfect. I've never taken linear algebra though. I understand mathematics better in a programming language form. Is there any way someone could put that in a pseudocode? (I know I should take classes, but currently very broke)

Comment: The linear algebra used in that post would probably only be covered in a week or two. Just google "vector cross product".

Answer (score 1):

This might not directly answer your question, but to make things much simpler for you I would recommend you use box 2d.

There are 2 implementation for javascript:

- [box2dweb](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) which is the most up to date convert of a port.
- [box2d js](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) which is the first (older direct port)

This lib is really good at 2d physics/collisions.